# undefined method `fields_for' for #<MyModel:0xc2f8da0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 level hierarchy in my models for e.g

Publisher [have many] -> Author [have many] -> Book

In My form, 
I have the following structure

```
<%= form_for(@publisher) do |p| %> 
    ...
  <%= p.fields_for @publisher.authors.build, :authors do |a| %>
     ...
    <%= a.fields_for a.books.build, :books do |b| %>
      ...
    <% end %> 
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

It throws the following error

```
undefined method `fields_for' for #<Author:0xc2f8da0>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you set accepts_nested_attributes_for in your models?

Comment: Yes, got them in both the models

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you're trying to call `fields_for` on an instance of the `Author` class (which is a model). The method isn't defined on the model, it's a helper method that's part of [ActionView](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Try simply removing `a.` and do:

```
<%= fields_for a.books.build, :books do |b| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

There are more examples in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). This may not be the full answer to your situation, but anytime you'te getting `undefined method` errors, the problem is very straight forward - you're calling a method that doesn't exist either in the scope, or the object upon which you're calling it. Usually this happens because you think you're dealing with an object of class `x`, but really you've got class `y` and you didn't realize it.

Comment: If I remove a then I get "can't convert Symbol into Integer". I got it working (but only show...) still struggling with save part.

Comment: If you post the error (either revise your question, or write a new one) I might be able to help you out with that. I'll need the actual error and stack trace.

Comment: With the following code, It displays the form...  But when I post the form... Authors are added properly.. but when I post book, it makes author and book attributes blank. 
    <%= form_for(@publisher) do |p| %> 
    ...
      <%= p.fields_for :authors do |a| %>
     ...
        <%= a.fields_for :books do |b| %>
      ...
        <% end %> 
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in all the necessary models? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Yes, I have accepts_nested_attributes_for in 
In Publisher:
  has_many :authors, :foreign_key => :publisher_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors  
  attr_accessor :milestone
In Author:
  has_many :books
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books #, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessor :book

I have a table in which I display Authors (with top to add an Author) and for table inside the row for each author to show / add books. 
It allows me to add books most recent added Author but for others it doesn't return any data in the request. This problem is driving me nuts.. Please help. Ta.

Comment: Huh. Sounds right. Not sure without seeing the full form code, and the params form the dev log. If you want to post that in a gist, feel free, and I can try to take a look.